# Openlayers - Many broken tiles with vmap WMS in EPSG:900913

Tags: openlayers-2, wms

I would like to use the vmap WNS (http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0) in an OpenLayers map. I encounter many broken tiles (pink) when using the srs: EPSG:90013 contrary to EPSG:4326 and that at every zoom level.

[image]

I would like to know what could be the cause(s), and if it's a problem on the server side or on the client side.

```
  map = new OpenLayers.Map('map',
            { projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913") });

  openL = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( "OpenLayers WMS",
                "http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0", {layers: ['basic','stateboundary','coastline_01'],
                                    srs: 'EPSG:900913',
                                  isBaseLayer: true
                                  });
  map.size = new OpenLayers.Size(1000,800);
  map.addLayer(openL);
  var bounds = new OpenLayers.Bounds.fromArray([-180.0, 90.0, 180.0, -90.0]);
  map.zoomToExtent(bounds.transform(source,dest));
```

Comment: Pink tiles indicate error response from server, you can either right-click on the broken tiles and copy the URL or look into your browser's network tab and search for failed (red) image requests. Opening the tile URL in another tab will show an HTML or XML page with error details.

Comment: Just so that you know, these tiles are from osgeo, and there is no guarantee that they will always work. If you want to use tiles in a production environment, you should host your own tiles, or use a service which has a SLA